# Firebase batch() function is not updating multiple documents

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to update multiple documents in firebase using batch. The function is running without any errors but it is not updating the required fields

```
let newDbRef = db.collection( 'oldusers' ).where( 'userName', '==', newUserName.value )
        newDbRef.onSnapshot( ( querySnapshot ) =>
        {
            querySnapshot.forEach( ( doc ) =>
            {
                var batch = db.batch()
                batch.update(newDbRef, {'userName': newUserName.value})
                batch.commit().then( () =>
                {
                    console.log('profiles updated...');
                })
            })
        })
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should not declare and commit the batch in the `forEach` loop. Declare it before the loop and commit it after the loop,  when you have added all the updates operations, as follows:

```
  let newDbRef = db
    .collection('oldusers')
    .where('userName', '==', newUserName.value);

  newDbRef.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    var batch = db.batch();
    
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      batch.update(newDbRef, { userName: newUserName.value });
    });
    
    batch.commit().then(() => {
      console.log('profiles updated...');
    });
  });
```

---

Note that, since you use `onSnapshot()`, the batched updates will occur **each time the query results change** (that is, when a document is added, removed, or modified).

Comment: It is giving an error, Expected type 'fp', but it was: a custom lp object

Comment: With the code you share in your answer it is very hard to help you on the error you mention in your comment. You need to share more.